# SQL - Employee Number 000001234 need to remove first 4 zeros but keep the rest

Tags: sql-server

I have searched but either missed the answer or didn't understand the ones I did find. I am a very basic SQL user.

Employee number column was originally setup to be 9 digits and to have leading zeros. Now the client only wants 5 digits and I need to remove 4 of the 5 leading zeros from the employee number column in the employee table.

I have tried select LTRIM '0000' from EmpComp where EecEmpNo ='' and get an error of invalid column name.

I have tried select ltrim ('0000' from eecempno) from EmpComp with an error as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Michael S.

Comment: uhm....it sounds to me that you want `RIGHT(EmployeeNumber,5)`?

Comment: `UPDATE EmpComp
SET EecEmpNo = RIGHT(EecEmpNo, 5)`

Comment: Even better would be to change the datatype to an int and forget about the silliness of leading 0's in the database. That should be a presentation layer thing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I am not able to change the data types as I am simply doing an implementation and have no control over the database structure.

Answer (score 2):

`LTRIM` only handles leading whitespace.  You want to use the `LEFT` or `RIGHT` function.

```
 SELECT RIGHT(EecEmpNo, 5)
 FROM EmpComp
```